# permission for user profile image

Tags: media, users

I would like to give permission for user profile image to registrant users only. i.e. anonymous user who visit the site can see the default profile image only in the user list and registrant users can see the real image of the user. 
How can I make it? Does it required changing the setting or utilizing view? 
Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The easy way then is to hard code this into your theme.

Open your template.php file in your theme's root folder. Add the following function in that file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_picture(&$vars){
  if (!$vars['logged_in']) {
    // user is anonymous
    $path = variable_get('user_picture_default', FALSE);
    $style = variable_get('user_picture_style', FALSE);
    if ($path && $style) {
      $vars['user_picture'] = '<img src="' . image_style_url($style, $path) . '" />';
    }
    else {
      $vars['user_picture'] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Replace MYTHEME with the machine name of your theme (similar to the MYTHEME in MYTHEME.info file). Then make sure you add a default picture at:

```
admin/config/people/accounts
```

The easiest is to just paste in this in the Default picture text box:

```
public://default-picture.png
```

and under the folder sites/default/files include the default-picture.png file. But that is obviously just a suggestion and you can put your picture anywhere.

If you don't see any default picture when viewing the site as anonymous then your default picture path is incorrect. Test it by creating a new user without a picture.

Comment: This is likely how I would do it too, although I may sway towards putting it in a custom module instead of the theme. To generate the image markup you could also use theme('image_style') if the image module is enabled or theme('image') if it is not.